# Rejected by sanitizer - Bootstrap Glyphicons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3.3.7 in my app and in Mozilla Firefox I get an error **"downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:1)"**.

Bootstrap is added this way in index.html `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">` and later in production this file is concatenated and compressed.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue because I googled it but couldn't find the solution?

Comment: Is it possible the asset to which you are linking is somehow corrupt? What happens if you link to the official CDN: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Comment: @RobertC Not sure. I will try it and let you know.